# Can we find a binary operation s.t. the map $\phi(n)=n+1$ becomes an isomorphism from $\langle\Bbb Z,*\rangle$ onto $\langle\Bbb Z,.\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

> Can we find a suitable binary operation $*$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ such that the map $\phi : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined as $\phi(n)= n+1$ becomes an isomorphism from $\langle \mathbb{Z}, *\rangle $ onto $\langle \mathbb{Z}, .\rangle$ ?
> Here $.$ is the Usual multiplication.

This is a lot easier if the group $\langle \mathbb{Z}, +\rangle $ is considered instead of $\langle \mathbb{Z}, .\rangle$. Because then $a*b = a+b+1$ works just fine. But how can I define the operation here?

**Edit :** I think I got the hang of the answer from Arthur's comment.

Let, $a*b = (a+1)(b+1) - 1$.

Then, $\phi(a*b) = (a+1)(b+1) = \phi(a) \cdot \phi(b)$.
I think this is correct.

Can anyone give me some hint?

Comment: The magic words are ["transport of structure"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Rephrase your $(\Bbb Z,+)$ solution from $a+b+1$ to $(a+1)+(b+1)-1$. Now see if you can't apply the same tactic.

Comment: Okay let me see.

Comment: Actually I did but if I'm rephrasing $a*b = (a+1)+(b+1)-1$ as you said then it's not working. But $a*b = (a+1)(b+1) -1$ is working. Am I correct?

Comment: Let, $a*b = (a+1)(b+1)-1$. Then, $\phi(a*b) = (a+1)(b+1) = \phi(a) \cdot \phi(b)$. I think it's correct.

Comment: @Itachi Exactly. To make it easier to see the general pattern, what we have done is to set $a*b=\phi^{-1}(\phi(a)\cdot \phi(b))$ (while your addition example has $a*b=\phi^{-1}(\phi(a)+ \phi(b))$).

Answer (score 0):

If $\phi$ is an isomorphism then you know the inverse. The operation is the one induced by $(\mathbb{Z},+)$.